# Understanding `std::is_move_constructible`

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts `const T&` arguments, satisfy `std::is_move_constructible`. For example, in the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct T {
    T(const T&) {}
    //T(T&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<T>::value, "not move constructible");
    return 0;
}
```

`T` will have no implicit move constructor as it has a user-defined copy constructor.

However, if we uncomment the explicit delete of the move constructor, the code no longer compiles. Why is this? I would have expected that the explicit copy constructor would still satisfy `std::is_move_constructible`.

Does overload play a role, choosing the declared move constructor and then failing because it is deleted?

---

If this difference between move constructibility between a `no implicit move ctor` and a `deleted move ctor` class is mandated by the standard, please quote, and if possible, give a rationale (like "to provide a facility for forbidding move construction"—first thing that jumps to mind).

Comment: Yes, explicitly declaring the move constructor as deleted explicitly declares it, thus it is involved in overload selection and it is the match selected by `is_move_constructible`. Then, because it is deleted, this fails and static assert fails.

Comment: This was by far the simplest explanation...

Comment: He is referring to the `static_assert` that I used in my code -- it does fail.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a complete revamp of my first answer, to correct some mistakes said and to have quotes from the standard and to nail some details the questioner wishes.

**What `std::is_move_constructible` actually do**

If `T` is a structure then `std::is_move_constructible<T>` evaluates to `std::is_constructible<T,T&&>`.  `std::is_constructible<T,U>` is valid if `T x(y)` is a well-formed expression for some `y` of type `U`.  Thus for `std::is_move_constructible<T>` to be true, `T x(std::move(y))` must be well-formed for `y` of type `T`.

Quotes from the standard:

```
The predicate condition for a template specialization is_constructible<T, Args...>
shall be satisﬁed if and only if the following variable deﬁnition would
be well-formed for some invented variable t:
    T t(create<Args>()...);
```

(...)

```
Template: template <class T> struct is_move_constructible;
Condition: For a referenceable type T, the same result as is_constructible<T, T&&>::value,
           otherwise false.
Precondition: T shall be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) void,
              or an array of unknown bound.
```

**When a move constructor is created**

The standard says a default move constructor is created only when no copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator or a destructor has been declared by the user.

```
If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
—X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
—X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
—X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
—X does not have a user-declared destructor
```

However the standard allows you to initialize a class lvalue-reference with a class rvalue.

```
Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type
(i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.
—If the initializer expression is an xvalue (but not a bit-ﬁeld),
class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and “cv1 T1”
is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or (...)
then the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression (...)
(or, in either case, to an appropriate base class subobject).
```

Thus if you have a copy constructor `T::T(S& other)` and an object `y` of type `T&&`, i.e. a rvalue reference to `T`, then `y` is reference-compatible with `T&` and `T x(y)` is a valid expression to call the copy constructor `T::T(S&)`.

**What the example struct do**

Let me go with your first example, removing the `const` keywords, to avoid stating ten times that the reference needs to be more cv-qualified than the initializer.

```
struct S {
    S(S&) {}
};
```

Let's check the condition.  There is no implicitly defaulted move constructor since there is a user-defined copy constructor.  However, 
if `y` is of type `S`, then `std::move(y)`, of type `S&&`, is reference compatible with type `S&`.  Thus `S x(std::move(y))` is perfectly valid and call the copy constructor `S::S(const S&)`.

**What the second example do**

```
struct T {
    T(T&) {}
    T(T&&) = delete;
};
```

Again, no move constructor is defined as there is a user defined copy constructor *and* a user-defined move constructor.  Again let `y` be of type `T` and consider `T x(std::move(y))`.

However, this time multiple constructor can fit in the expression, so an overload selection is performed.  Only the most specialized matching constructor is attempted to work with so only the move constructor `T::T(T&&)` is attempted to call to.  But the move constructor is deleted, so this is invalid.

**Conclusion**

The first struct, `S`, can use its copy constructor usable to perform a move-like expression, as it is the most specialized constructor for this expression.

The second struct, `T`, have to use its explicitly declared move constructor to perform the move-like expression, again because it is the most specialized.  However that constructor is deleted, the move-construction expression fails.

Comment: This is also a restatement of my question. I have already stated all this. The questions is, why? Why does it make a difference whether the move ctor is deleted or non-existent?

Comment: You didn't read fully the details: "The copy constructor can be used to move an object if no move constructor is defined."  If you explicitly delete a move constructor, you actually define a move constructor (that cannot be used).  Let me add that last statement.

Comment: So the move constructor can be absent, implicitly declared and defined, implicitly declared and deleted, explicitly defaulted and explicitly defined. And overload resolution always chooses the move constructor if it is declared (except in C++14, where [deleted implicit move constructors are ignored](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor), I presume). In other words, copy ctor will work only if move ctor is completely absent, correct?

Comment: Nit-pick: In *"if `T x(y)` is a well-formed expression"*, the `T x(y)` is not an expression (it is a declaration and definition).

Comment: *"Thus if you have a copy constructor `T::T(S& other)` ...."* this gets multiple details wrong; probably all of them unimportant: A constructor `T::T(S&)` is only a copy-constructor if `S` is `cv T` (where `cv` is any combination of `const` and `volatile` or lack thereof). A variable with reference type is not an object. Value categories (lvalue, rvalue, ..) apply to *expressions* only; an id-expression that refers to a variable declared as rvalue-reference is an lvalue-expression (!). Reference-compatibility is applied to the types referred to, so `y` is reference-compatible with `T`.

Comment: There is a little-known detail in the treatment of references in the Standard: Expressions which initially have reference type (e.g. `auto foo() -> S&;` then the expression `foo()`) are stripped of their referenceness; the reference is used to determine the value category. Wherever the expression `foo()` occurs, it is treated as an lvalue-expression of type `S` (not `S&`!). Therefore, let `S s;`, then of course `std::move(s)` is reference-compatible with `S`. The value category and (nonexisting) reference type operator do not matter in this case.

Answer (score 6):

### Overview

A move constructible class is a class that either has a move constructor, either implicit or user declared. Or a copy constructor that is called for rvalue references. These constructors would be evoked, unless the class has a deleted move constructor.

Consequently:

```
struct T {
    T(const T&) {}
};
```

Is a move constructible class and thus you get true from the respective trait.

Declaring though the move constructor `delete`:

```
struct T {
    T(const T&) {}
    T(T&&) = delete;
};
```

Makes your class non move constructible.

### Why this happens?

Even though the move constructor is delete, it participates in the overload resolution as if it wasn't delete. Thus, as a direct match is prefered.

For `is_move_constructible` to provide the member constant `value` true the variable definition `T obj(T&&);` must be well-formed, if you delete the move constructor of `T` is ill-formed. Thus, you get value equal to false.

Now as for how this can happen in compile time. Look for the magic of `std::declval`. `std::declval` is used somewhere is the implementation of the trait to evaluate if a move of the class object is possible with out actually evaluating the expression.

Answer (score -1):

in my tests, the answer seems to be wrong again. by the way, I have tested the following code on MSVC 17 and GNU 6.3:

```
struct T {
   T(const T&) {}
};
static_assert(is_move_constructible<T>(), "");
T a;
T b(move(a)); // compiler error here
```

according to here[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor], the user-defined copy constructor will disable the implicit default move constructor. the code can not be compiled. 
but strangely, the meta function is_move_constructible<> says yes, and the compiler complains that the error is happend in position: T(b(move(a));

so, in my opinion, the implementation of is_move_constructible has some defects.

---

my mistake, I forgot the default constructor here.

Comment: Your code works flawlessly under GCC 6.1, 7.1 and 7.2. There is at least one obvious error in your code: missing default constructor, and potentially an include/namespace issue that might have led you to your conclusion that the move doesn't work. Try the code in https://gist.github.com/Irfy/6da0f8b11e95c9c05a12e572e1a0b4bc