# Why are implicitly and explicitly deleted move constructors treated differently?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

What is the ***rationale*** behind the different treatment of implicitly and explicitly deleted move constructors in the C++11 standard, with respect to the implicit generation of move constructors of containing/inheriting classes?

Do C++14/C++17 change anything? (Except [DR1402](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1402) in C++14)

Note: I understand what is happening, I understand that it is according to the C++11 standard's rules, I'm interested in the rationale for these rules that imply this behavior (please make sure not to simply restate that it is the way it is because the standard says so).

---

Assume a class `ExplicitDelete` with an explicitly deleted move ctor and an explicitly defaulted copy ctor. This class isn't `move constructible` even though a *compatible* copy ctor is available, because overload resolution chooses the move constructor and fails at compile time due to its deletion.

Assume a class `ImplicitDelete` which either contains or inherits from `ExplicitDelete` and does nothing else. This class will have its move ctor implicitly declared as deleted due to [C++11 move ctor rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor). However, this class will still be `move constructible` via its copy ctor. (Does this last statement have to do with resolution of [DR1402](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1402)?)

Then a class `Implicit` containing/inheriting from `ImplicitDelete` will have a perfectly fine implicit move constructor generated, that calls `ImplicitDelete`'s copy ctor.

So what is the rationale behind allowing `Implicit` to be able to move implicitly and `ImplicitDelete` not to be able to move implicitly?

In practice, if `Implicit` and `ImplicitDelete` have some heavy-duty movable members (think `vector<string>`), I see no reason that `Implicit` should be vastly superior to `ImplicitDelete` in move performance. `ImplicitDelete` could still copy `ExplicitDelete` from its implicit move ctor—just like `Implicit` does with `ImplicitDelete`.

---

To me, this behavior seems inconsistent. I'd find it more consistent if either of these two things happened:

1. The compiler treats both the implicitly and explicitly deleted move ctors the same:

   - `ImplicitDelete` becomes not `move-constructible`, just like `ExplicitDelete`
   - `ImplicitDelete`'s deleted move ctor leads to a deleted implicit move ctor in `Implicit` (in the same way that `ExplicitDelete` does that to `ImplicitDelete`)
   - `Implicit` becomes not `move-constructible`
   - Compilation of the `std::move` line utterly fails in my code sample
2. Or, the compiler falls back to copy ctor *also* for `ExplicitDelete`:

   - `ExplicitDelete`'s copy constructor is called in all `move`s, just like for `ImplicitDelete`
   - `ImplicitDelete` gets a proper implicit move ctor
   - (`Implicit` is unchanged in this scenario)
   - The output of the code sample indicates that the `Explicit` member is always moved.

---

Here's the fully working example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Explicit {
    // prints whether the containing class's move or copy constructor was called
    // in practice this would be the expensive vector<string>
    string owner;
    Explicit(string owner) : owner(owner) {};
    Explicit(const Explicit& o) { cout << o.owner << " is actually copying\n"; }
    Explicit(Explicit&& o) noexcept { cout << o.owner << " is moving\n"; }
};
struct ExplicitDelete {
    ExplicitDelete() = default;
    ExplicitDelete(const ExplicitDelete&) = default;
    ExplicitDelete(ExplicitDelete&&) noexcept = delete;
};
struct ImplicitDelete : ExplicitDelete {
    Explicit exp{"ImplicitDelete"};
};
struct Implicit : ImplicitDelete {
    Explicit exp{"Implicit"};
};

int main() {
    ImplicitDelete id1;
    ImplicitDelete id2(move(id1)); // expect copy call
    Implicit i1;
    Implicit i2(move(i1)); // expect 1x ImplicitDelete's copy and 1x Implicit's move
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly but what would be the point of declaring a function `delete`d in the first place if the compiler would just get clever finding ways to avoid calling it?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not assuming the rules are bad and I know better, but rather, that with my *limited knowledge* I do not understand the reasons for current behavior -- it seems inconsistent in the context of what I know. I have added a small section just before the code sample to answer your question.

Comment: My first impression was that your alternative behaviour (1) made the most sense; however after further thought, it does make sense that `Implicit` on your example can answer a move-request by moving the movable parts, and copying the non-movable parts.

Comment: @M.M.: Exactly. I'd prefer (2) because it allows for more efficient automatically generated code without any apparent deficits. -- However, I do not agree with your statement that `ImplicitDelete` can move implicitly. It is `move-constructible`, no doubt, but its implicit move ctor is deleted, as per the rule ["T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible destructor"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor). It move-constructs via its implicit copy ctor -- and that is my point, `ExplicitDelete` should too.

Comment: If you apply [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939687/how-can-i-check-if-a-move-constructor-is-being-generated-implicitly/33947209#33947209) to [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939687/how-can-i-check-if-a-move-constructor-is-being-generated-implicitly), you will see that even when you explicitly default `ImplicitDelete`'s move ctor, it will not be generated(!) So the copy ctor is used as a fallback even then. OTOH, it wouldn't make sense to generate a move ctor that will still just copy my `Explicit` object.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Irfy/666c68d0d4c973a12bdf) with the generated output below the code. gcc 5.2.0 in gnu++11 mode.

Comment: My guess for this behavior is that by explicitly `delete`ing something you're saying "*it's a bad thing if I get selected, so slap my hand if that happens*". But with an explicitly `default`ed constructor, `ImplicitDelete` shouldn't have to worry about all of its base classes and data members, so in that case if the move constructor would be ill-formed, it's simply ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So what is the rationale behind allowing Implicit to be able to move implicitly and ImplicitDelete not to be able to move implicitly?

The rationale would be this: the case you describe does not make sense.

See, all of this started because of `ExplicitDelete`. By your definition, this class has an explicitly deleted move constructor, but a defaulted copy constructor.

There are immobile types, with neither copy nor move. There are move-only types. And there are copyable types.

But a type which can be copied but has an *explicitly deleted* move constructor? I would say that such a class is a contradiction.

Here are the three facts, as I see it:

1. Explicitly deleting a move constructor is supposed to mean you can't move it.
2. Explicitly defaulting a copy constructor is supposed to mean you can copy it (for the purposes of this conversation, of course. I know you can still do things that make the explicit default deleted instead).
3. If a type can be copied, it can be moved. That's why the rule about implicitly deleted move constructors not participating in overload resolution exists. Therefore, movement is a proper subset of copying.

The behavior of C++ in this instance is inconsistent because your code is contradictory. You want your type to be copyable but not moveable; C++ does not allow that, so it behaves oddly.

Look at what happens when you remove the contradiction. If you explicitly delete the copy constructor in `ExplicitDelete`, everything makes sense again. `ImplicitDelete`'s copy/move constructors are implicitly deleted, so it is immobile. And `Implicit`'s copy/move constructors are implicitly deleted, so it too is immobile.

If you write contradictory code, C++ will not behave in an entirely legitimate fashion.

Comment: This is interesting. "Every object should be either only movable, or both movable and copyable, but not just copyable." I guess the language allows me to shoot myself in the foot if I'm explicit about it (pun intended). So my example is too synthetic and truly immovable objects *really should* also be non-copyable, because otherwise it doesn't make any practical sense. I think I like your answer. If I find a practical counter-example for immovable but copyable, I'll come back.