# What do explicitly-defaulted constructors do?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default, default-constructor

Consider the following:

```
template <class T>
struct myclass
{
    using value_type = T;
    constexpr myclass() = default;
    constexpr myclass(const myclass& other) = default;
    constexpr myclass(const myclass&& other) = default;
    T value;
};
```

- To what constructor bodies these function are equivalent?
- Does `myclass<int> x;` initialize the integer at `0`?
- For `myclass<std::vector<int>> x;` what does the default move constructor do? Does it call the move constructor of the vector?

Comment: Did you mean to make the move constructor parameter `const`?

Comment: I think `constexpr myclass(const myclass&& other) = default;` is actually ill-formed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They aren't equivalent to any function bodies. There are small but significant differences between the three cases: `= default`, allowing implicit generation, and the nearest equivalent function body.

The following links explain in more detail:

- [Defaulted default constructor and destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor)
- [Defaulted move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003210/explicitly-defaulted-move-constructor)

I couldn't find a good link about copy-constructor; however similar considerations as mentioned in the other two links will apply.

---

`myclass<int> x;` does not set `value` to `0`.

The defaulted move-constructor (if you made it a non-const reference) moves each movable member  (although I think there is a special case where if there is a non-movable base class, weird things happen...)

Comment: IIRC, if there is a non-moveable base or non-static data member, the explicitly defaulted move constructor will be defined as deleted.

Comment: @Praetorian could you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988934/why-are-implicitly-and-explicitly-deleted-move-constructors-treated-differently?noredirect=1#comment55747826_33988934) from yesterday? I wasn't able to grok what was going on, the `ImplicitDelete` class has a non-movable base, but moving it does compile

Comment: I don't know the *why* part, but the OP's description is correct - *[class.copy]/11 - A defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted is ignored by overload resolution*. So `ImplicitDelete`'s move constructor is ignored by overload resolution and the copy constructor is the next viable candidate, so moving it will result in copying.

Comment: @Praetorian ok, thanks for that. So there is an exception to the rule that deleted functions participate in overload resolution.. clear as mud :)

Comment: Are you sure that `myclass<int> x;` does not set value to `0`? If I use the value without initialization, neither g++ or clang++ give me a warning (and in both cases, it is set to 0).

Comment: @Vincent Yes I'm sure. Compiler warnings are irrelevant. Trying to output an uninitialized variable causes undefined behaviour, you might see anything. See [dcl.init]/12 of C++14

Comment: [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e16e2bc8a432ec81) currently shows non-zero for me... results may vary between runs of course